# OpenWebRTC needs back-end server?

Tags: ios, webrtc

OpenWebRTC has the iOS library.  Does anyone know OpenWebRTC required a back-end server?

Comment: BackEnd for what purpose? I would assume it needs a way to handle signalling between the parties.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a signalling server is needed. An example is available here: https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-examples/tree/master/web

Note that this is the same code that runs for http://demo.openwebrtc.org:38080/